# JAX-RS JAXB Jackson not using @XmlRootElement name

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson, jax-rs

I am developing a restful application with JAX-RS and JAXB. I want to send following Entity as JSON to my client:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDTO implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    // getter & setter
}
```

The method in my WebService is defined as follows:

```java
@POST
@Path("users/{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public UserAccountDTO login(@PathParam("id") Long id)
{
    UserAccountDTO userAccount = loadUserAccount(id);
    return userAccount;
}
```

First problem was, that the root node was not send via JSON. Therefore I have added following Class:

```java
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SkedFlexContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public SkedFlexContextResolver() throws Exception
    {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType)
    {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Now, the root node is send with the data. In case of XML everything is fine (root node is equal to name of `@XmlRootElement`). See following XML response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
  <id>10</id>
  <username>Admin</username>
  <firstname>Administrator</firstname>
</user>
```

But in case of JSON the root node is the Classname of the POJO:

```json
{
    "UserAccountDTO":
    {
        "id": 10,
        "username": "Admin",
        "firstname": "Administrator",
        "lastname": null
    }
}
```

Why differs the output between XML and JSON? What do I need to change to get the specified name in the `@XmlRootElement`-Annotation

Comment: Why did you enable `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`?

Comment: Found any answer yet? Same problem here. It looks like the Jackson wrapper ignores the name property

Answer (score 4):

I had to register Jaxb module to the xml mapper like this, otherwise the `@XmlRootElement(name = "myname")` was igonerd.

```
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing `.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)` to `.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)` should help.

According to [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE):

> Feature that can be enabled to make root value <..> wrapped within a single property JSON object, where key as the "root name"

Comment: If I change it to `.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)` the root node is missing in the response data. The JSON mentioned in my question is fine, except that it does not repsect the name givenin the `@XmlRootElement`

Comment: @Develman oh, i misunderstood you. For using jaxb annotation you should register jaxb module. Did you do that? See 'Usage' https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```